# Help me understand my wiring

Tags: wiring, hvac, thermostat

I have a two zone system in my new house with 2 separate thermostats. I am trying to replace my thermostat on the first floor which I believe controls the second zone and is connected to the air handler in the attic.

When I opened up the thermostat I only see R,G and Y wires connected to it even though there is a spare white wire in the wall. The ques I am stumped is whether the setup I have currently can control both heating and cooling on the first floor or not. I assumed as much but not sure since the W wire is not even connected to the thermostat.

I am trying to install a nest smart thermostat and when I hook up the same R,G and Y wires to it …it only shows cooling as an option. But I can feel hot air through my vents.

What’s my setup here ..can anyone help ?

Rahul

Comment: The R W G Y are names of wires that do particular functions.  You (and the last guy) are allowed to use any actual wire color you want, for any of them.  (there's a certain elegance to using Red White Green Yellow respectively, but it's not a Code requirement) .  As such, you cannot assume colors correspond to letters, and must investigate the connections down at the furnace and see what was done.  It's possible the white wire had a problem.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at both the air-handler and thermostat ends please?

Comment: Will post Pics tomorrow.